# Equivalent to Oracle external tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Is there an equivalent to [Oracle's External Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) in SQL Server ?

An external table is a table which is mapped to a flat-file in the filesystem.

It is very convenient since it allows you to read a flat-file as a table with standard SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Harold Javier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877928/1083652) is a good one,
but you might also want to consider using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) with the `BULK` keyword.

It is different from the external table because you don't "create" a table but more of a query.

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT et.*
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'your_data_file', FORMATFILE = 'your_format_file.fmt') AS et
```

Instead of giving the format in the table definition (as in oracle), you should add a `fmt` file.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx) is how to create it

Answer (score 2):

You need to create external links. Creating a linked server using the Text IISAM is one. You may also check this link:(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to sql server 2016 to get what you need.

Comment: I think the EXTERNAL TABLEs in the 2016 version are only for Hadoop/Polybase not regular file system files.