# Oracle control file equivalent in sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, data-import

I have oracle generated control file `.ctl` file and text file containing the data I need to import.

I need to import this data in text file into SQL Server table and using this .ctl file.

Oracle has built in command like `SQLLDR` which does this stuff, but is there any equivalent for this for SQL Server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx

Comment: Not exactly the same but maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877196/equivalent-to-oracle-external-tables-in-sql-server) can help

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a utility for bulk loading/unloading of data, which is called **[bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)**

You can use bcp to load the data from your text file into the tables of SQl Server database.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much.
I have used BCP utility, but it is not useful in current scenario.
I have control file(.ctl) file which has table structure which helps for us to get the data from file (txt) file accurately. And it is processed through SQLLDR utility in Oracle, but I think, we dont have utlity like Oracle...?