# Delphi - multiple inserts in loop into MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, delphi, insert

I need to loop throw tstringlist and execute insert for each item. Now My code is :

```
 for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
      begin

        aqZapisz.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
          '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, '
          + 'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
          'VALUES(:p1,:p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13)';
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').Value := idk;
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p2').Value := TS2[i];
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p3').Value := edtNrDok.Text;
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p4').Value := edtPoz.Text;
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p5').Value := id_grupy;;

        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p6').Value := id_rodzaju;
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p7').Value := id_typu;
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p8').Value :=
          DateToStr(zxDateDok.Date);
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p9').Value :=
          DateToStr(zxDatePlat.Date);
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p10').Value :=
          DateToStr(zxDateKsieg.Date);
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p11').Value :=
          IntToStr(Integer(MonthOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p12').Value :=
          IntToStr(Integer(YearOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
          aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p13').Value :=
            RoundTo((StrToFloat(edtWartosc.Text) /
            listazaznprojektow.Count), -2);

        aqZapisz.ExecSQL;
        aqZapisz.SQL.Clear;

      end;
```

But the insert  time is ~2 minutes with 1700 items in TS2. How can I increse the speed  ??

Comment: Do some searching for bulk inserts.

Comment: Try to use external table as described, for example, here: [Equivalent to Oracle external tables in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877196/equivalent-to-oracle-external-tables-in-sql-server). It works much faster then interpret data as on-by-one rows. BTW it works on the server side only.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the speed with

1. a single transaction

   ```pascal
   Connection.StartTransaction;
   try

     // Send the data to the server

     Connection.Commit;
   except
     ConnectionRollback;
   end;
   ```
2. splitting the data into the fixed and dynamic part, so you do not have to send the same data again and again to the server. Store the fixed part into a temporary table and use it for every insert with the dynamic data
3. reuse the already prepared query -> do not set the sql statement inside the loop or clear it to have to set it again
4. reuse the already set **fixed parameters** (alternative to 2.)

A quick solution would be

```pascal
aqZapisz.Connection.StartTransaction;
try
  aqZapisz.SQL.Text :=
    'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
    '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, ' +
    'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
    'VALUES(:p1,:p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13)';

  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p1' ).Value := idk;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p3' ).Value := edtNrDok.Text;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p4' ).Value := edtPoz.Text;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p5' ).Value := id_grupy;;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p6' ).Value := id_rodzaju;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p7' ).Value := id_typu;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p8' ).Value := DateToStr( zxDateDok.Date );
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p9' ).Value := DateToStr( zxDatePlat.Date );
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p10' ).Value := DateToStr( zxDateKsieg.Date );
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p11' ).Value := IntToStr( Integer( MonthOf( zxDateKsieg.Date ) ) );
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p12' ).Value := IntToStr( Integer( YearOf( zxDateKsieg.Date ) ) );
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p13' ).Value := RoundTo( ( StrToFloat( edtWartosc.Text ) / listazaznprojektow.Count ), -2 );

  for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
    begin
      aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p2' ).Value := TS2[i];

      aqZapisz.ExecSQL;
    end;

  aqZapisz.Connection.Commit;
except
  aqZapisz.Connection.Rollback;
  raise;
end;
```

---

You should measure how much time the application and server task will take to get a hint if it is worth to implement (2.).

The newer Delphi versions have a convenient [`System.Diagnostics.TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) for that case.

```pascal
var
  LInternal, LServer : TStopWatch;
begin
  LServer := TStopWatch.Create;
  LInternal := TStopWatch.StartNew;

  ...

    for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
      begin
        aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName( 'p2' ).Value := TS2[i];

        LServer.Start;

        aqZapisz.ExecSQL;

        LServer.Stop;
      end;

  ...

  LInternal.Stop;

  ShowMessage( 
    Format( 
      'Total: %dms Server: %dms',
      [ LInternal.ElapsedMilliseconds, LServer.ElapsedMilliseconds ] ) );

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace your SQL statement every time through the loop. Set it once, before the loop starts, and then just update the parameters inside the loop.

```
aqZapisz.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
      '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, '
      + 'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
      'VALUES(:p1,:p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13)';

for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
begin
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').Value := idk;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p2').Value := TS2[i];
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p3').Value := edtNrDok.Text;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p4').Value := edtPoz.Text;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p5').Value := id_grupy;;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p6').Value := id_rodzaju;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p7').Value := id_typu;
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p8').Value :=  
    DateToStr(zxDateDok.Date);
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p9').Value := 
    DateToStr(zxDatePlat.Date);
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p10').Value := 
    DateToStr(zxDateKsieg.Date);
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p11').Value :=
      IntToStr(Integer(MonthOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p12').Value :=
      IntToStr(Integer(YearOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
  aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p13').Value :=
      RoundTo((StrToFloat(edtWartosc.Text) /
        listazaznprojektow.Count), -2);

  aqZapisz.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Comment: It appears only parameter p2 is being changed, unless I'm overlooking something. I think you could make it even more efficient by moving all the parameters except p2 before the loop.

Comment: I tested both sugestions - all parameters  in loop, and  only p2 in loop. Result = maybe 5 seconds better than with old code,but still too long ;( Maybe is it possible to send to  sql server command and all parameters (with ts2)  and insert it in  loop,but "inside" sql server without transfer every insert  over network  ? Something like stored procedure with for loop...

Comment: @user1762186 Also try to eliminate access to parameters by name (each time Delphi searches it in the parameters list). Declare some variables as `p1, p2, ...: TParam;` and then, before loop `p1 := aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p1')...` and use `p1.Value := ...` instead of `aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').Value := ...` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest hit is that you are doing multiple SQL statements one after the other. This involves calling the server, waiting for a response and all of the extra traffic that goes with that. You have a couple of options:

1) You can try and add all of your sql statements one after the other and then do one execsql statement at the end. You will need to "cheat" and inline the p2 parameter. If you opt for this route you should clean that parameter yourself to prevent things like SQL injection. You could also do this in batches of X records.

```
baseSQL1 := 'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
      '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, '
      + 'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
      'VALUES(:p1, '+
baseSQL2 := ', :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13);';

aqZapisz.SQL.Clear;
for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
begin
  aqZapisz.SQL.Add(baseSQL1 + TS2[i] + baseSQL2);
end;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').Value := idk;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p3').Value := edtNrDok.Text;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p4').Value := edtPoz.Text;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p5').Value := id_grupy;;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p6').Value := id_rodzaju;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p7').Value := id_typu;
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p8').Value :=
  DateToStr(zxDateDok.Date);
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p9').Value :=
  DateToStr(zxDatePlat.Date);
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p10').Value :=
  DateToStr(zxDateKsieg.Date);
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p11').Value :=
    IntToStr(Integer(MonthOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p12').Value :=
    IntToStr(Integer(YearOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
aqZapisz.Parameters.ParamByName('p13').Value :=
    RoundTo((StrToFloat(edtWartosc.Text) /
      listazaznprojektow.Count), -2);
aqZapisz.ExecSQL;
```

2) You can create a stored proc and send through all of the data in one go. Totally untested.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (@p1 nvarchar(max), @p2 nvarchar(max), @p3 nvarchar(max), @p4 nvarchar(max), @p5 nvarchar(max), @p6 nvarchar(max), @p7 nvarchar(max), @p8 nvarchar(max), @p9 nvarchar(max), @p10 nvarchar(max), @p11 nvarchar(max), @p12 nvarchar(max), @p13 nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idx1 INT;
    DECLARE @idx2 INT;
    SET @idx1=0;
    WHILE @idx1 >-1
    BEGIN;
        SELECT @idx2 = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),@p2,@idx1);
        IF @idx2 > 0
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb 
                  (id_kosztu, id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja, id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, data_pla, data_ksi, mc,rok,kwota)
                  VALUES(@p1, SUBSTRING(@p2,@idx1,@idx2-@idx1), @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13)

            SET @idx1 = @idx2 + 2;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb 
                  (id_kosztu, id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja, id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, data_pla, data_ksi, mc,rok,kwota)
                  VALUES(@p1, SUBSTRING(@p2,@idx1,LEN(@p2)+1-@idx1), @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13)

            SET @idx1 = -1;
        END;
    END;
END;
```

Call the procedure and pass in p2stringlist as @p2:

```
for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do
begin
  p2stringlist.Add(TS2[i]);
end;
```

Comment: What is the   ` @ str ` in ` VALUES(@p1, SUBSTRING(@p2,@idx1,LEN(@str)+1-@idx1), @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13) `  because is is undeclared ?

Comment: I try the first method but result is the same. The longest  part of execute code is the for loop - it takes soooo long :(

Comment: @user1762186 `@str` was supposed to be `@p2`.

Comment: @user1762186 How can the for loop still be slow? It's adding a bunch of values to a TStringlist. If that is the case then your problem has nothing to do with the SQL at all.

Comment: you have right - this is the problem with tstringlist. When I  build in the same loop simple normal string  (` s := s + baseSQL1 + TS2[i] + baseSQL2` ) it works very fast,but when in the loop is ` aqZapisz.SQL.Add(baseSQL1 + TS2[i] + baseSQL2); `  it add 1700 records in ~ 5 minutes :(

Comment: @user1762186 How big is TS2[i]?

Comment: TS2[i] is just  1-4 digits (it is foreign key  of another table). So the size of the TS2[i] may grown in future (when users add records to this table)

Comment: Is your dbms local or somewhere on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Delphi do you use? Where is your database located (WAN or LAN)? 
If you have newer versions like XE4-XE7, you can try to use FireDAC FDQuery 
and it's [Array DML](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Array_DML_%28FireDAC%29) features (submits a single DBMS command with an array of parameters.).

Your code would look like this:

```
with FDQuery1 do begin
    SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
          '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, '
          + 'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
          'VALUES(:p1,:p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13)';
    // Set up parameter types
    Params[0].DataType := ftInteger;
    Params[1].DataType := ftString;
    Params[1].Size := 40;
    Params[2].DataType := ftString;
    Params[2].Size := 40;
    Params[3].DataType := ftString;
    Params[3].Size := 40;
    Params[4].DataType := ftString;
    Params[4].Size := 40;
    Params[5].DataType := ftInteger;
    Params[6].DataType := ftInteger;
    Params[7].DataType := ftInteger;    
    Params[8].DataType := ftString;
    Params[8].Size := 40;
    Params[9].DataType := ftString;
    Params[9].Size := 40;
    Params[10].DataType := ftString;
    Params[10].Size := 40;
    Params[11].DataType := ftString;
    Params[11].Size := 40;
    Params[12].DataType := ftString;
    Params[12].Size := 40;
    Params[12].DataType := ftFloat;

    // Set up parameters' array size
    Params.ArraySize := TS2.Count;
    // Set parameter values
    for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do begin
      Params[0].AsIntegers[i] := idk;      
      Params[1].AsStrings[i] := TS2[i];
      Params[2].AsStrings[i] := edtNrDok.Text;
      Params[3].AsStrings[i] := edtPoz.Text;
      Params[4].AsIntegers[i] := id_grupy;
      Params[5].AsIntegers[i] := id_rodzaju;
      Params[6].AsIntegers[i] := id_typu;
      Params[7].AsStrings[i] := DateToStr(zxDateDok.Date);
      Params[8].AsStrings[i] := DateToStr(zxDatePlat.Date);
      Params[9].AsStrings[i] := DateToStr(zxDateKsieg.Date);
      Params[10].AsStrings[i] := IntToStr(Integer(MonthOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
      Params[11].AsStrings[i] := IntToStr(Integer(YearOf(zxDateKsieg.Date)));
      Params[11].AsDouble[i] := RoundTo((StrToFloat(edtWartosc.Text) / listazaznprojektow.Count), -2); 

    end;
    // Execute batch
    Execute(TS2.Count, 0);
  end;
```

You can also try [RemoteSQL](http://www.gofastsoft.com/) which is much faster and deals with slow performances on latent networks.
Your basic code could look like this:

```
procedure AddParams(aServerSQLParams: TRemoteSerializableSQLParams; aParamName: string; aFieldType: TFieldType; aValue: Variant);
var
  MyParam: TRemoteSerializableSQLParam;
begin
  MyParam := TRemoteSerializableSQLParam(aServerSQLParams.AddParameter);
  MyParam.Name := aParamName;
  MyParam.DataType := aFieldType;
  MyParam.Value := aValue;  
end;

procedure SaveMyData;
var
  MySerSQLParams: TRemoteSerializableSQLParams;
begin

 try
     RemoteSQL_Handler1.StartTransaction;
     MySerSQLParams:= TRemoteSerializableSQLParams.Create;

     for i := 0 to TS2.Count - 1 do begin

        MySQL := 'INSERT INTO projekty_koszty_rozb ' +
              '(id_kosztu,id_projektu, nr_dokumentu, pozycja,id_grupy, id_rodzaju, id_typu, data_dok, '
              + 'data_pla, data_ksi,mc,rok,kwota) ' +
              'VALUES(:p1,:p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9,:p10,:p11,:p12,:p13)';

        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p1', ftInteger, idk);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p2', ftString, TS2[i]);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p3', ftString, edtNrDok.Text);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p4', ftString, edtPoz.Text);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p5', ftInteger, id_grupy);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p6', ftInteger, id_rodzaju);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p7', ftInteger, id_typu);
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p8', ftString, DateToStr(zxDateDok.Date));
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p9', ftString, DateToStr(zxDatePlat.Date));
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p10', ftString, DateToStr(zxDateKsieg.Date));
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p11', ftString, IntToStr(Integer(MonthOf(zxDateKsieg.Date))));
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p12', ftString, IntToStr(Integer(YearOf(zxDateKsieg.Date))));
        AddParams(MySerSQLParams, 'p13', ftFloat, RoundTo((StrToFloat(edtWartosc.Text) / listazaznprojektow.Count), -2));

        RemoteSQL_Handler1.ExecuteSQL(MySQL, MySerSQLParams);
      end;
      RemoteSQL_Handler1.CommitTransaction;
  except
    RemoteSQL_Handler1.RollBackTransaction;
    FreeAndNil(MySerSQLParams);
  end;

  FreeAndNil(MySerSQLParams);
end;
```

RemoteSQL collects your queries, compresses them and send them to server side at once(batch).