# Insert from stringgrid to MSSQL

Tags: delphi

I need to copy data from a stringgrid into a MSSQL database table. The table had already been created using a sql statement. We need to copy 4 different table with many fields. Is there any very effective code to grab all data and save them into the database table.  If not, I can code a loop sequence  and insert the data row by row. But this seems to be very slow and not flexible.

Comment: Why are you using a TStringGrid and not a TDBGrid?  Delphi's TDataSet descendants, like TAdoQuery for Sql Server dbs, amongst others, do all the work for you, if you let them.  Btw, which Delphi version?

Comment: Check this answer: [Equivalent to Oracle external tables in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14997345/593144) In few words: you should to create file on disk with data and then deal with it like with rowset. It must to work much faster then row by row inserts. And server need the access to this file.

Comment: I changed the code from stringgrid to read excel via ADO into a dbgrid , but now how to copy from one grid into a MS SQl database , will ask a new question.  Pls. close this  question

Comment: The grid has nothing to do with the copying process.  I suggest you ask your new q in terms of how to copy data using ADO from an Excel table to a Sql Server db.(but try searching on it first, because you are hardly the first to ask).