# Linking a SQL Server table to a text file without SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016-express

I want to link a SQL Server table to a text file so that any changes made to the text file, such as creating, deleting, or updating a row, are reflected in the SQL Server table.

The best way to do this appears to be SSIS, but I know that this is only for certain versions of SQL Server. I don't appear to have one of these versions, and this is not likely to change anytime soon.

Is it possible to achieve this result without SSIS?

Update: I am working with SQL Server 2016 Express.

Example of text file:

```
ITEM NUMBER   ;LINE          ;LOCATION         
1234432       ;SHIPPING      ;505R13201C
```

Comment: In Oracle you can use External Tables. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877196/equivalent-to-oracle-external-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: SSIS would be much easier...  You could potentially 'roll your own' stored procedure. Here would be a good place to start https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/a139245d-f63e-477f-8175-11f5b0e160cf/stored-procedure-to-import-data-from-csv-files?forum=transactsql